# Cannot find data adapter to handle input on model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset that is read and converted to NumPy arrays before going into the model.predict(). The goal is to use Keras to make predictions, however, after predicting 400 something values, I receive an error:

```
Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'tuple'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'float\'>", "<class \'numpy.float32\'>"})'}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

This error occurs when model.predict() is called in my code:

```
if len(models) > 0:
    for i in range(len(models)):
        path = models[i]['path']
        model = models[i]['model']
        inpt = to_input[i]
        p = model.predict((inpt,))[0][0]
        predictions.append((path, ann_type[i], p, target_time))
```

I've tried to convert inpt to numpy array, but the same error is evoked. The value of inpt at the time of the error is `[23.3, 23.32, 23.33, 23.35, 23.44, 23.49, 23.0, 22.88, 23.95, 24.45]`. What is missing here?

Comment: try this : `model.predict(inpt)[0][0]`, for example `(1, )` is a tuple with one element

Comment: @l'mahdi It doesn't work, because I need to have a shape of 10, but like so, I have a size of 1

Comment: OK, But input `model.predict((inpt, ))` is wrong,  How the input shape of 10 is another question. if you want shape 10 you can try like `inpt = to_input[i:i+10]`

Comment: @l'mahdi using that goes back to the error :\

Comment: Is this working ? `model.predict(np.random.rand(1,10))`

Comment: @l'mahdi No, it shows Error when checking input: expected flatten_10_input to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: so try this : `model.predict(np.random.rand(10))`

Comment: @l'mahdi doesn't work either

Comment: @l'mahdi I think I'm close. I converted inpt to np.asarray and then tried p = model.predict(inpt[0])[0][0]. It shows a different error which is Error when checking input: expected flatten_10_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (). How do I resize it?

Comment: Check this : `p = model.predict(inpt[0][None,:])[0][0]`

Comment: @l'mahdi no, says invalid index to scalar variable

Comment: I think it's better to insert your model and sample input and error that you get.

Comment: @l'mahdi I re-trained the models and it works again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, have good time ;)